# Android - How to catch java.io.IOException: no space left on device

Tags: android, memory, file-io, out-of-memory

Just to clear it up this is on an actual device and not an emulator.
I have a file set up that I store images in and suddenly the device will give a no space left on device warning in the logcat. I can see that I have room left in memory but for some reason it just wont save any more files. Im using small numbers to name the images so I dont have crazy name sizes.

Right now I have about 80 or so images in the file before it gives that error.

Im thinking I can catch the out of space error and empty the file and I know I should probably do this by checking how full the space actually is and how much room I have left but I havent tried to figure that out yet.

Another problem that I have is that Im telling the app to store the data on the sd card with

```
android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

but its storing the data on the internal memory. I have all my permissions set up and everything but for some reason its storing on internal rather than external.

So can some one point me to some info on how check for the amount of memory available for the storage of my app and also maybe some hints on why I end up storing to internal when Im trying to store on external.

Comment: Im also running out of room for new images which a user can take on the phone which is weird. When I use the in app camera it never saves a file to the directory I have set up for it to be stored in. Is it possible Ive reached the limit for the amount of data that my app can use or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `android.od.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.getPath()`

Check [this](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ecede996463a4058?pli=1) out.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Any thoughts on why its placing everything internal memory?

Comment: I'm guessing, but if you were not using .getPath(), it might be defaulting to internal memory.I have app that saves image. What I do is create a new folder in external memory, append it to path and save images.

Comment: Cool Ill give it a shot and post back with the result :)

Comment: That didnt do it because the directory being used is supposedly on the sd. By using .getPath() it only added mnt/sdcard to an an address that was like mnt/sdcard/data/...... Ill have to do some more research I guess

Comment: refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: I finally figured it out. On the current device I was testing on there were a lot of games and some other content streaming apps that were taking up memory. As soon as I got rid of those other apps that were eating up memory it worked fine.